# Octopus Release Versioning

Tags: version, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am using Octopus deploy for the CD process. I would like to know the difference between
Octopus.Version.NextPatch Vs Octopus.Version.Next. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#{Octopus.Version.Next}` isn't a valid [release versioning template variable](https://octopus.com/docs/releases/release-versioning). The expected format for these variables is

- Octopus (Denoting system variables)
- Version (Denoting versioning variables)
- Next OR Last (Selecting either the previous release version or the upcoming)
- One of any of the following - `Major|Minor|Patch|Build|Revision|Suffix` (Selecting the specific part of the version identifier)

So, in a project where you have `0.0.2` as the last successful release, `#{Octopus.Version.NextPatch}` will evaluate to `3`, where `#{Octopus.Version.Next}` will fail to evaluate and remain un-expanded.